# MassTransit Azure Servicebus Error Pipe configuration

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

MassTransit's default error pipe configuration sends faults to the _error queue as explained in the docs - [Error Pipe](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#error-pipe).

Instead, we want our consumers to rely on AZ servicebus default redelivery mechanism [PeekLock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#peeklock) where faulted messages are redelivered N times and if all N deliveries fault then message is moved into the servicebus queue's dead-letter.

couple questions:

If I configure my consumers error pipe like this

```
configurator.ConfigureError(x =>
{ 
   x.UseFilter(new RethrowErrorTransportFilter()); 
});
```

will message faults use the default service bus redelivery mechanism? Or is it enough to just use the DiscardFaultedMessage extension to prevent _error queue and rely on servicebus redelivery. If not, how do I configure the error pipe to get this behavior.

MT defines dead-letter as no consumer registered for the message type on the receive endpoint, and the message gets moved into the _skipped queue - [Dead Letter](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#error-pipe). Does the MassTransit DeadLetter pipe configuration have any effect on whether messages that exhaust their servicebus max-deliveries end up in servicebus dead-letter queue.

Edit - possible answer - [Is there a way to have MassTransit just abandon messages on error rather than forward to an error queue/deadletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145349/is-there-a-way-to-have-masstransit-just-abandon-messages-on-error-rather-than-fo?rq=1)

Comment: The possible answer is indeed correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to have MassTransit just abandon messages on error rather than forward to an error queue/deadletter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145349/is-there-a-way-to-have-masstransit-just-abandon-messages-on-error-rather-than-fo)