MassTransit AWS SQS: Do not create queues from code
We are currently using MassTransit to listen to AWS SQS queues, with our primary use case being read-only access. However, during initialization, MassTransit requires sqs:CreateQueue and sqs:DeleteQueue permissions, which we would like to avoid.
Our infrastructure has already provisioned the necessary queues for _skipped and _error scenarios. Is there a configuration option within MassTransit that allows us to specify the names of these pre-existing queues and prevent any queue creation or deletion via code?
Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/72896960/1882
